# Remove domain extension

Tags: php, regex

So let's say I have `just-a.domain.com,just-a-domain.info,just.a-domain.net` how can I remove the extension `.com,.net.info ...` and I need the resultes in two variables one with the domain name and another one with the extension.

I tried with `str_replace` but doesn't work, I guess only with regex....

Comment: What parts should www.google.co.uk return?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$subject = 'just-a.domain.com';
$result = preg_split('/(?=\.[^.]+$)/', $subject);
```

This produces the following array

```
$result[0] == 'just-a.domain';
$result[1] == '.com';
```

Comment: works, but only for domains with one DOT in the extension. E.g. for ".com.br" it won't work.

Comment: @almo Get the result using the script then again split the result :)

Answer (score 12):

```
  preg_match('/(.*?)((?:\.co)?.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $domain, $matches);
```

$matches[1] will have the domain and $matches[2] will have the extension

```
<?php

$domains = array("google.com", "google.in", "google.co.in", "google.info", "analytics.google.com");

foreach($domains as $domain){
  preg_match('/(.*?)((?:\.co)?.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $domain, $matches);
  print_r($matches);
}
?>
```

Will produce the output

```
Array
(
    [0] => google.com
    [1] => google
    [2] => .com
)
Array
(
    [0] => google.in
    [1] => google
    [2] => .in
)
Array
(
    [0] => google.co.in
    [1] => google
    [2] => .co.in
)
Array
(
    [0] => google.info
    [1] => google
    [2] => .info
)
Array
(
    [0] => analytics.google.com
    [1] => analytics.google
    [2] => .com
)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to remove the part of the domain that is administrated by domain name registrars, you will need to use a list of such suffixes like [the Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/).

But since a walk through this list and testing the suffix on the domain name is not that efficient, rather use this list only to build an index like this:

```
$tlds = array(
    // ac : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ac
    'ac',
    'com.ac',
    'edu.ac',
    'gov.ac',
    'net.ac',
    'mil.ac',
    'org.ac',
    // ad : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ad
    'ad',
    'nom.ad',
    // …
);
$tldIndex = array_flip($tlds);
```

Searching for the best match would then go like this:

```
$levels = explode('.', $domain);
for ($length=1, $n=count($levels); $length<=$n; ++$length) {
    $suffix = implode('.', array_slice($levels, -$length));
    if (!isset($tldIndex[$suffix])) {
        $length--;
        break;
    }
}
$suffix = implode('.', array_slice($levels, -$length));
$prefix = substr($domain, 0, -strlen($suffix) - 1);
```

Or build a tree that represents the hierarchy of the domain name levels as follows:

```
$tldTree = array(
    // ac : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ac
    'ac' => array(
        'com' => true,
        'edu' => true,
        'gov' => true,
        'net' => true,
        'mil' => true,
        'org' => true,
     ),
     // ad : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.ad
     'ad' => array(
        'nom' => true,
     ),
     // …
);
```

Then you can use the following to find the match:

```
$levels = explode('.', $domain);
$r = &$tldTree;
$length = 0;
foreach (array_reverse($levels) as $level) {
    if (isset($r[$level])) {
        $r = &$r[$level];
        $length++;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
$suffix = implode('.', array_slice($levels, - $length));
$prefix = substr($domain, 0, -strlen($suffix) - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex and `parse_url()` aren't solution for you.

You need package that uses [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only in this way you can correctly extract domains with two-, third-level TLDs (co.uk, a.bg, b.bg, etc.). I recomend use [TLD Extract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).

Here example of code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('just.a-domain.net');
$result->getSubdomain(); // will return (string) 'just'
$result->getHostname(); // will return (string) 'a-domain'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return (string) 'net'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return (string) 'a-domain.net'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
strrpos($str, ".")
```

Will give you the index for the last period in your string, then you can use `substr()` with the index and return the short string.