# Separating the extention from its domain name

Tags: php, explode

I want to work around email addresses and I want to explode them using php's explode function.

It's ok to separate the user from the domain or the host doing like this:

list( $user, $domain ) = explode( '@', $email );

but when trying to explode the domain to domain_name and domain_extention I realised that when exploding them using the "." as the argument it will not always be foo.bar, it can sometimes be foo.ba.ar like fooooo.co.uk

so how to separate "fooooo.co" from "uk" and let the co with the fooooo. so finally I will get the TLD separated from the other part.

I know that co.uk is supposed to be treated as the TLD but it's not official, like fooooo.nat.tn or fooooo.gov.tn

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not official"?

Comment: Well, *co.uk* is not a top level domain but a second level domain (*uk* is the top level domain).

Comment: that's it as Gumbo said. co.uk is not listed as a TLD as well as com.tn nat.tn ....

Comment: But there are lists that contain these second level domains as well (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`strripos()`](http://www.php.net/strripos) to find the last occurrence of ".":

```
$blah = "hello.co.uk";

$i = strripos($blah, ".");

echo "name = " . substr($blah, 0, $i) . "\n";
echo "TLD = " . substr($blah, $i + 1) . "\n";
```

Comment: thank you for your reply mr Oli but could you give me a little example?

Answer (score 1):

Better use [`imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist`](http://php.net/imap_rfc822_parse_adrlist) or [`mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses`](http://php.net/mailparse_rfc822_parse_addresses) to parse the email address if available. And for removing the “public suffix” from the domain name, see [my answer to *Remove domain extension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853338/remove-domain-extension/3853473#3853473).

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Oli's answer...

```
substr($address, (strripos($address, '.') + 1));
```

Will give the TLD without the '.'.  Lose the +1 and you get the dot, too.

Comment: Ahh, seems Oli expanded his answer.  It's better than this, so +1 to Oli.

Answer (score 0):

`end(explode('.', $email));` will give you the TLD. To get the domain name without that, you can do any number of other string manipulation tricks, such as subtracting off that length.

Comment: thank you sir but this gave me a wrong result:

when I used fooooo@ymail.com.tn, this gave me t as the firs result and n as the second result it separated .tn to t n