# PHP Remove Domain Name Extension from String

Tags: php, string, function, dns

I was wondering of the best way of removing certain things from a domain using PHP.

**For example:**

"*http://mydomain.com/*" into "*mydomain*"

or

"*http://mydomain.co.uk/*" into "*mydomain*"

I'm looking for a quick function that will allow me to remove such things as:

"http://", "www.", ".com", ".co.uk", ".net", ".org", "/" etc

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [As a quick note] I'll be using a string/variable that will store the domain ($var = "http://domain.com/";).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are You trying do that?

Comment: It's just for adding info to a database on a new project I'm working on. When I print the data in profile pages etc I don't want to have incorrect domain extensions, So I want to phrase them myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get the host part of a URL use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url):

```
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
```

And for the rest see [my answer to *Remove domain extension*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853338/remove-domain-extension/3853473#3853473).

Answer (score 1):

Could you use string replace?

```
str_replace('http://', '');
```

This would strip out 'http://' from a string. All you would have to do first is get the current url of the page and pass it through any string replace you wanted to..

Comment: I want to go about stripping the "http://" and any domain extension such as ".com" or ".net". Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I would str_replace out the 'http://' and then explode the periods in the full domain name.

Comment: Gumbo explains it better above, go with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine parse_url() and str_* functions, but you'll never have correct result if you need cut domain zone (.com, .net, etc.) from your result.

For example:

```
parse_url('http://mydomain.co.uk/', PHP_URL_HOST); // will return 'mydomain.co.uk'
```

You need use library that uses [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/list/) for handle such situations. I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract).

Here is a sample code:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

$result = $extract->parse('mydomain.co.uk');
$result->getHostname(); // will return 'mydomain'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'co.uk'
$result->getFullHost(); // will return 'mydomain.co.uk'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'mydomain.co.uk'
```