# How do you remove TLD from domain name with php/ regex

Tags: php, regex

This is the code I have so far.

```
$main = 'example.com';

$removed = str_ireplace("cant figure out what to put in here...", " ", "$main");
echo $removed;`
```

I know I can just put .com in the first paramerter but there are hundreds of different TLD'S im trying to remove.

Comment: Just asking... Why you want to remove the TLD from a URL...?

Comment: Please, look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Bergi, im not very good at php yet, but i have tried .com | .org etc  etc didnt really want to do it like that because there are hundreds. But it didnt work anyways. I have been working on this all night. Frederick, i want to remove it so i can count the characters in the domain minus the tld

Comment: serge i have read that page 100 times tonight :( thank you though

Comment: What happens if somebody enters bbc.co.uk? If the answer is bbc, then you'll need to use a big lookup table of some kind. Otherwise, it's just a strrpos/substr problem.

Comment: i have experience with regex in other things just not php you should be able to do something like this  \.(.*) replace  which would get rid of anything after the first occurrence of a period but cant figure out how to do this in php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove domain extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853338/remove-domain-extension)

Answer (score 2):

Use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to strip the URL down, and [http-build-url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) to build it back up after removing the host.

A simple example (warning - may not work, I'll explain why afterwards) is.

```
$url = "http://example.com:port/path?query=parts&so=on";
$aParts = parse_url($url);
$aParts['host'] = '';
$removed = http_build_url($aParts);
echo $removed;
```

But this may not work for two reasons:

1. http_build_url is an http function not always installed in PHP. You may need to get from PECL, but before you do...
2. the functions are very fussy about building strict URLs, and so you may want to actually create it yourself.

So a better solution would be to:

```
$url = "http://example.com:port/path?query=parts&so=on";
$aParts = parse_url($url);
$aParts['host'] = '';
$removed = ($aParts['host'] ? $aParts['host'] : 'http') . '://'
           '' .   // This is where the host goes
           ($aParts['post'] ? ':' . $aParts['port'] : '') .
           ($aParts['path'] ? '/' . $aParts['path'] : '') .
           ($aParts['query'] ? '?' . $aParts['query'] : '') .
           ($aParts['fragment'] ? '#' . $aParts['fragment'] : '');
```

(Not tested - apologies for any bugs but you shouldge the idea)

Add in user and pass if required (check the docs linked above) and if you want to replace the host not leave blank - you an see where to do it.

Comment: That seems like a lot to do to remove anything after the first occurrence of a period. The url always comes to me with no http:// no sub directory it is always example.com example.org example.me example1.me example.co.uk  All i want to do is use a regex code to remove anything after the first . Im starting to think regex cant be used with str_ireplace that may be what my problem is.

Comment: preg_replace or preg_match is what you want for regular expressions.

Comment: Or do you only get the domain, not a url. In which case, stristr() will work wonders for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with Thanks to robby for pointing me in the right direction.

```
$url = 'example.com.uk';
$removed  = stristr($url, '.',true);
echo  "$removed";
```