# Getting domain extension from URL?

Tags: php

I want to get the domain extension from the url. eg. .com, .net etc.

I have used this:

```
$extension = pathinfo($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

I was just wondering if there was a better way using parse_url?

Comment: Better use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

Comment: How do you want to handle `.co.uk`?

Answer (score 10):

Use `parse_url()`. Something like:

```
$host = parse_url('http://www.google.co.uk/test.html');
preg_match('/(.*?)((\.co)?.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $host['host'], $m);

$ext = isset($m[2]) ? $m[2]: '';
```

Edit: Fixed with regex from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3853468). Extension like .co.uk are supported too.

Comment: This doesnt work with domains such as .co.uk

Comment: @user1794021, try the edited version.

Comment: Returns `Undefined index: host`

Comment: `(.*?)((?:\.co|.com)?.[a-z]{2,4})$` if you want to support .com.xx  extensions (such as .com.au).

Answer (score -3):

You can easily split the requested URI like this:

```
function tld( $uri ) {
    $parts = explode('.', $uri);

    return (sizeof($parts) ? ('.' . end($parts)) : false;
}
```

So you can do this:

```
if(!tld('googlecom')) // does not contain an ending TLD

if(tld('google.com')) // this is a valid domain name; output: ".com"
```

---

Or you can just use:

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
```

So in my oppinion the most best example of usage is:

```
echo tld($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
```