# Get domain name from url without tld

Tags: php, dns, tld

I need to know how to get the domain name from a url without the tld.

This is what I have **that works for .com**, .info, etc **but not for .co.uk**

```
// get host name from URL
preg_match('@^(?:http://)?([^/]+)@i',
"http://example.co.uk", $matches);
$host = $matches[1];

// get last two segments of host name
preg_match('/([^.]+)\.[^.]+$/', $host, $matches);
echo "domain name is: {$matches[1]}\n";
```

When I get it to call **"example.co.uk"** domain it just shows: **"co"** when I need it to show **"example"**

Thanks

Comment: You need a list of public suffixes.

Comment: Specifically, you need the [Public Suffix List](http://publicsuffix.org/).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853338/remove-domain-extension/3853473#3853473

Comment: Where would i add the Public Suffix List?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is falsy solution there, you need package that using [Public Suffix List](https://publicsuffix.org/), only with it you can get correct result on complex TLDS.

I recomend [TLDExtract](https://github.com/layershifter/TLDExtract) for domain parsing, here is sample code that show diff:

```
$extract = new LayerShifter\TLDExtract\Extract();

# For 'http://www.domain.com/site'

$result = $extract->parse('http://www.domain.com/site');
$result->getFullHost(); // will return 'www.domain.com'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'domain.com'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'com'

# For 'http://www.domain.co.uk/site'

$result = $extract->parse('http://www.domain.co.uk/site');
$result->getFullHost(); // will return 'www.domain.co.uk'
$result->getRegistrableDomain(); // will return 'domain.co.uk'
$result->getSuffix(); // will return 'co.uk'
```