# Get domain name from URL - PHP

Tags: php

I need to get domain name from URL

domain.com

domain.co.uk

I should get:

.com

.co.uk

I tried with explode function but doesn't display domain ".co.uk"(example)

```
    <?php
$url = "domain.com";

$host = explode('.', $url);

print $host[1];
?>
```

Comment: there are built in php functions for this - i'll let you go find them

Comment: Problem is that you are exploding a domain with two dots. It will get only what is after the last dot.

Comment: i think and with preg_replace can solve, but i don't know much php.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

UPDATE based off (currently third answer) - 
[Remove domain extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853338/remove-domain-extension/3853473#3853473)

```
$url = 'php.co.uk';
preg_match('/(.*?)((?:\.co)?.[a-z]{2,4})$/i', $url, $matches);
```

print_r($matches);

---

IGNORE FOLLOW - Bad practice, but still explains working of explode.

See when you explode and you use '.', it finds it twice in .co.uk.
So if you where to echo both $host[1] & $host[2] you would get co uk respectively.

So as a partially complete (not sure what your end game is) solution:

Solution:

```
$url = "domain.co.uk";

$host = explode('.', $url);
$first = true;
foreach($host as $hostExtension){
  if($first){
      $first = !$first;
      continue;
  }
 else{
      echo $hostExtension .'<br>';
  }
}
```

To be clear though, the other answers explain how you should be parsing the URL. I just merely thought to explain why (answering the question) your code was doing/return what it was and how you would get your intended result.

Comment: terrible idea. use the built in functions not explode

Comment: I agree, but I thought to explain why he wasn't getting his intended result.

Comment: @Dagon, Have you any idea for this, i would be grateful.

Comment: See the thing is, usually I'd have recommended.
pathinfo or parse_url, but according to those .uk is the extension and .co belongs to the domain name.

Comment: @mrtest did you try parse_url () ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3853338/remove-domain-extension/3853473#3853473 - currently third answer is the only working example I found.

Comment: @Valdorous, thanks for ur answer, but i guess this thing can solve and with preg_replace but this function confuse me !

Comment: I edited the answer to add a working example for you. What it does is it creates an array. The first in the array is the full URL, the second is the domain half and the third is the extension (regardless of .'s). 

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, use php function `parse_url` (http://php.net/parse_url), it will help you.

Comment: mrtest speaks spanish?

Comment: Short version so it displays whatever the requestors language is: http://php.net/parse_url

Comment: Please don't just link but quote the relevant part oft the link in the answer.